# Runas command do not allow to enter my password, immediatly return to command prompt

Tags: windows, runas

When using **runas** to run **explorer.exe** as admin, I can't even enter my password, indeed I get the following message `Enter the password for admin:` but it immediatly return to the command prompt, preventing me to enter my password.

The command I'm using is `runas /user:admin explorer.exe`

And it's on Windows 7 (Version 6.1.7601).

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire command you're trying to do, and tell us which version of windows you're using.

Comment: @LPChip I just edited ;)

Comment: Tested this on windows 8 and 10. It works there. Don't have a windows 7 here to test on. Do note that explorer.exe is also the process for the windows taskbar and desktop. It may be the reason why it doesn't work.